# PDF Generation Help needed

Tags: pdf

I am brandnew to PDF Generation or rendering but have a project to, create a PDF Template system that allows users to save Template to Database, 
and later generate a PDF document using the template and values from my database.

Language to use C#

Questions

a) Is there a PDF tool out there that can help me with this and documentation I can study to learn of this? 
b) Are there free tools out there for this?
c) How do I create a PDF Template? XML?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is there a particular language you would like to use to undertake your project?

Comment: As Oren said  - you need to specify any other constraints such as programming language/environment since there are many ways to create PDFs

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at xsl:fo.
Apache has a [tool](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to create and modify PDFs. (Everything below is completely free.)

Here are two extensive tutorials on generating PDFs in PHP:

http://blog.eirikhoem.net/index.php/2008/04/28/populate-pdf-templates-with-php-fpdf-fpdi/

http://www.astahost.com/info.php/create-pdf-php_t4972.html

You can use the [FPDF library](http://www.fpdf.org/) located [here](http://www.fpdf.org/) to handle generating PDFs based off of templates.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Java, you could try [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) or [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) - they work from templates and can produce PDF output dynamically based on data and those templates.  Depending on your template requirements, you might also be able to use Jasper Reports or Apache POI.  All have free versions.

Answer (score 0):

I would give a shot to [jsreport](http://jsreport.net). You can install it on premise for free or use it online. It supports html -> pdf transformation using phantomjs or xml -> pdf transformation using apache fop.

The idea is that first you create report template using javascript templating engines like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) in jsreport studio and then you get back pdf by calling jsreport api.

If you are in c# there is [jsreport c# sdk](http://jsreport.net/learn/net-client) for it.

Note: I am the author of jsreport

Comment: Jan, if you advertise a tool you have an active interest in (and you have in jsreport as it is something you are working on) please mention so in your answer. Answers on SO should be objective or have their subjectivity noted clearly if they are not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an instant solution, take a look on http://pdfnow.com . You can upload your XSL/FO-Templates and simply generate PDF-Templates with a simple webservice call.